# In Hive ,how to specify semi-column delimiters for struct data types with in custom delimiters serde2

Tags: hive, hiveql, hive-serde

I am trying to create table as below.

```
CREATE TABLE r_test (foo INT, bar STRING, address  STRUCT<street:STRING, city:STRING, state:STRING, zip:INT>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"field.delim"="<=>",
"collection.delim"="\;",
"mapkey.delim"="@"
    );
```

I  getting error in created table as follows

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 5:25 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting StringLiteral near '=' in specifying key/value property (state=42000,code=40000)
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with unicode character for semicolon i.e **\u003B**

```
hive> CREATE TABLE r_test (foo INT, bar STRING, address  STRUCT<street:STRING, city:STRING, state:STRING, zip:INT>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"field.delim"="<=>",
"collection.delim"="\u003B",
"mapkey.delim"="@"
    );
```

I created the table with unicode character and check the ***collection.delim is ;*** below:

```
hive> desc formatted r_test;
    | Storage Desc Params:| NULL                 | NULL                        |
    |                     | collection.delim     | ;                           |
    |                     | field.delim          | <=>                         |
    |                     | mapkey.delim         | @                           |
    |                     | serialization.format | 1                           |
```